# SQL 2019: Insufficient disk space to generate checkpoint

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2019 and a few databases. One works fine, but to the 2nd my app cannot connect:

> There is insufficient disk space to generate checkpoint files and as a
> result the database is in delete-only mode. In this mode, only deletes
> and drops are allowed.

This 2nd database (120 MB) has In-memory tables and has SQL Server 2016 compatibility level. I have checked volume space, disk has 200 GB free space.

What is the reason? what can I check?

Comment: Do the different databases store their files on different drives? Or their data files on different drives than their log files? Mabe a drive other than the one you checked is running out of space. Are you sure you've checked them all?

Comment: Or, is the disk that hosts the In-Memory checkpoint files a different disk than the one you checked?

Comment: All databases located on servers local  HDDs. There are free spaces: c: 1TB. d: 5TB, e: 500GB. And database has 120MB size.

Comment: Is the disk location for the MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup also on a disk that has plenty of free space?

Comment: I have re-checked: the MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup located on disk e: (500 GB free).

Comment: Well, that has exhausted my knowledge of in-memory things. Good luck.

Comment: Yet another thing: I have fixed the db: SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
SET OFFLINE;
SET ONLINE;
SET MULTI_USER;